# PhantomJS - Click an element don't load newpage and instead bring me back to login page

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, pageload, buttonclick

I am new to JavaScript and PhantomJs. I'd like to only have plain javascripts and not Jquery which I'd like to learn in the future.
My target is to download files from different website based upon the args which I would like to pass via .csv/.txt file.
However I got stuck.
I read all around how to achieve what I want and I came up with a script that load the page, insert username and password, click on the login button and enter inside the portal. From here I should put the mouse over a menu which open a submenu, then put again the mouse over one of the option which open another div which if clicked bring me to a newpage where I can insert input to search the files I need to download.
I've tried to make the button visible without move the mouse on the menu (which I dont even know how to achieve) by getting the div id of the element and change its visbility to "visible" and its display to "inline" and then .click() on it (dunno If i could achieve that even if the button still invisible).
Here I got stuck as it seems that I cant click on the button.
[PAGE AS I LOG IN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTOqC.png) // [DIV AT TOP LEFT AFTER CHANGE OF VISIBILITY AND DISPLAY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOiTa.png)

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');
var indice = 0;
var loadInProgress = false;
var div;


page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg){
                console.log(msg);
};
page.onAlert = function(msg) {
    console.log('alert!!> ' + msg);
};

page.onLoadStarted = function() {
    loadInProgress = true;
    console.log("*Caricamento pagina iniziato*");
};

page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {
    loadInProgress = false;
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Collegamento fallito !');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
                               page.render("foto" + indice +".png")
        console.log("*Caricamento pagina terminato*");
    }
};

interval = setInterval(function(){
                if (!loadInProgress && typeof steps[indice]=="function"){
                               if (indice==0){

                                               console.log("-Avvio portale...");
                                               steps[indice]();
                                               indice++;

                               }else if (indice==1){

                                               console.log("-Inserimento credenziali...");
                                               steps[indice]();
                                               indice++
                               }else if (indice==2){
                                               console.log("-Tentativo di login ...");
                                               steps[indice]();
                                               indice++
                               }else if (indice==3){
                                               console.log("-Apertura 'Ricerca misure XML' ...");
                                               steps[indice]();
                                               indice++
                               }else{
                                               console.log("Funzione successiva");
                                               indice++;
                               }
                }
                if (!loadInProgress && typeof steps[indice]!="function"){
                               console.log("-TERMINE PROGRAMMA-");
                               phantom.exit();
                }
},100);

var steps = [
function() {

                page.open("http://portal.reti.acsm-agam.it/Portal/Index.aspx?idn=0005&area=B2B");
},
function(){
                page.evaluate(function(){
                document.getElementById("twsTemplate_Content1_twsModule_txtUser").value="USERNAME";
                document.getElementById("twsTemplate_Content1_twsModule_txtPSW").value="PASSWORD";
                });
                page.render("credenziali.png");
},
function(){
//This click work with no problems
                page.evaluate(function(){
                               document.getElementById("twsTemplate_Content1_twsModule_btnLogin").click();
                });
},
function(){
//first attempt to click on the div
                page.evaluate(function(){
                               var div=document.getElementById("twsTemplate_Header1_Mainmenu2_aspMainMenun16Items");
                               div.style.display = "inline";
                               div.style.visibility="visible";
                               div.click();
                });
                page.render("visibilita.png")
},
function(){
//this is an attempt to directly open the new link since as human,after being logged I can change the url and it "feels" that I am already logged in and let me go the files search page. IT SEEMS THIS DONT LOAD AT ALL
                page.open("http://portal.reti.acsm-agam.it/Portal/Index.aspx?m=214G&area=B2B");

//actually trying this one just to be sure I am not just ignorant and try to get the span inside the div to be clicked. but still fail even if it seems that I can make the div to be visible as it goes on top left of the png image I make after.
        page.evaluate(function(){
            var DIVRICERCA=document.getElementById("twsTemplate_Header1_Mainmenu2_aspMainMenun16Items");
            DIVRICERCA.style.visibility="visible";
            DIVRICERCA.style.display="inline";
            var SPANSRICERCA= DIVRICERCA.getElementsByTagName("span");
            var SPANRICERCA=SPANSRICERCA[0];
            SPANRICERCA.click();

        });
page.render("visualizzaricerca.png");
},
function(){
                console.log("...");
}


];
```

So from the console where I expect the second page.open to fire the page.onLoadStarted event or when I use .click() to fire the same event but this dont happend. Here's the html code of the button i want to press:

```
</div><div id="twsTemplate_Header1_Mainmenu2_aspMainMenun16Items" class="twsTemplate_Header1_Mainmenu2_aspMainMenu_0">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(this)" id="twsTemplate_Header1_Mainmenu2_aspMainMenun21">
            <td><table class="livello2 twsTemplate_Header1_Mainmenu2_aspMainMenu_8" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100%;"><a class="twsTemplate_Header1_Mainmenu2_aspMainMenu_1 livello2 twsTemplate_Header1_Mainmenu2_aspMainMenu_7" href="/Portal/Index.aspx?m=214G&amp;area=B2B" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;"><span class='level2withoutchild livello2'>Ricerca file XML</span></a></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr>
```

Actually when I use this code

```
page.evaluate(function(){
    var DIVRICERCA=document.getElementById("twsTemplate_Header1_Mainmenu2_aspMainMenun16Items");
    DIVRICERCA.style.visibility="visible";
    DIVRICERCA.style.display="inline";
    var SPANSRICERCA= DIVRICERCA.getElementsByTagName("span");
    var SPANRICERCA=SPANSRICERCA[0];
    SPANRICERCA.click();

});
```

a page get loaded but the render show that I'm back to the login form instead in the new menu.

Comment: You should always use `page.onError` callback to be able to see if something goes wrong.

Comment: Do you **have** to use menu? The link to XML files clearly has an URL, can you not go there?

Comment: @Vaviloff Thanks for the tip, I dont know all the event I could use (not even so good to search in github the sourcecode) would like to learn and see what's happend and how work all those method.
I use the menu manually but I just need to go to the href link specified in the <a> tag as it's there where I am redirect when I click on the span with inner html "Ricerca file XML". I've tried as you saw to directly use page.open("actuallink/hreflink") but this wont load.